# Regex only grabbing first digit

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to grab everything after the following digits, so I end up with just the store name in this string:

full string: `/stores/1077029-gacha-pins`
what I want to ignore: `/stores/1077029-`
what I need to grab: `gacha-pins`

Those digits can change at any time so it's not specifically that ID, but any numbers after `/stores/`

My attempt so far is only grabbing `/stores/1`

```
\/stores\/[0-9]
```

I'm still trying, just thought I would see if I can get some help in the meantime too, will post an answer if I solve.

Comment: You may use: `~/stores/\d+-\K.+~` as regex or use `preg_replace` to replace `~/stores/\d+-~` with empty string.

Comment: `(\/stores\/[0-9]+-)(.*)$` capture group 2 will contain 'gacha-pins'

Comment: Maybe `'~/stores/\d+-\K[^/]+$~'`?

Comment: Hi Jordan, could you please review the answers below and let know which solution does work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
'~/stores/\d+-\K[^/]+$~'
```

Or a more specific one:

```
'~/stores/\d+-\K\w+(?:-\w+)*$~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W35IBN/1) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W35IBN/2).

**Details**

- `/stores/` - a literal string
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `[^/]+` - any 1+ chars other than `/`
- `\w+(?:-\w+)*` - 1+ word chars and then 0+ sequences of `-` and 1+ word chars
- `$` - end of string.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/1nGuj):

```
$s = "/stores/1077029-gacha-pins";
$rx = '~/stores/\d+-\K[^/]+$~';
if (preg_match($rx, $s, $matches)) {
    echo "Result: " . $matches[0];
}
// => Result: gacha-pins
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```
$string = '/stores/1077029-gacha-pins';
preg_match('#/stores/[0-9-]+(.*)#', $string, $matches);
$part = $matches[1];
print_r($part);
```

Comment: Besdies, the current pattern [will match](https://regex101.com/r/ut1yxm/1) `/stores/45677` in `/stores/1077029-/stores/45677` which is unlikely to be expected.